# I need the number in a cell to countdown when data is entered into other cells.

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I'm making a sheet to keep track of the number of software licenses.

In cell B1 I have the number 35 representing 35 licenses. As they are assigned to systems in cells C5-C40 I would like the total in cell B1 to count down reflecting remaining licenses.  So each time data is entered into any cell C5-C40 that number in B1 will count down

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing will be in the cells prior to you entering data:

```
=COUNTIF(C5:C40,"")
```

Comment: This does work but for some reason it changes the cell B1 from 35 and counting down to 36, every time.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not enough information for me to go on. Can you post what your sheet looks like? Or better yet, link to the workbook?

Comment: I can't post a pic yet, not high enough rating, and the workbook isn't online so I wouldn't really know how to post it so you can look at.. 

I have 35 licenses, 35 is in B1, when I paste your formula into B1, it works perfectly but shows 36 instead of 35, it just changes it to 36.. I appreciate your help also..

Comment: That is because there are 36 cells in range C5:C40. If you only have 35 license, adjust the range to the number of licenses you need. Also, please accept my answer if this works for you.

Comment: That was it, I'll try to learn from that, it didn't even cross my mind to alter the range.. THANKS..  I've got another question also but wasn't sure if I should make a new question or ask on here..

Comment: Make a new question, I will keep an eye out for it.

Comment: I've got another question for you about this formula. I'll post another question but wanted to give you a heads up if you've got the time..

Answer (score 0):

this is the formula you will need. I had an almost exact dilemma and this worked like a charm! Hope it does for you!

=35-COUNT(C5:C40)

Comment: You almost certainly would prefer COUNTA() to COUNT() here (assuming that using a count function is preferable to the approach taken in some other answers)

Answer (score -1):

if you enter =35-SUM(C5:C40) in cell B1 then each time you enter you enter a number value in cells c5 to c40 the number will then countdown as needed.

Comment: You probably want to count entries rather than sum the cell contents.

Comment: You *definitely* want to count, not sum.